# Why does this form validation for empty input values fail?

Tags: javascript, html

In my code there is a radio button group called `fitness` which has six options and they have values from `1` to `6`.
I have written a function to check whether the user has selected one of the above options:

```js
function fitnessValidate(form) { // Javascript function to check whether the user has selected some fitness option
  if (document.getElementById("fitness").value == null) { // Checking whether user has selected some option
    window.alert("Please select an option"); // If user has not selected an option providing an alert
    
    return false;
  }
  
  return true; // This function will only return true when user has selected a fitness option
}
```

```html
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:15px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="1" /> More than 1 hour – I will walk slowly and take several breaks
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="2" />1 hour - I will walk all the way in a normal pace
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="3" />45 minutes– I will walk all the way in a fast pace
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="4" />35 minutes – I will run in at an easy pace and take a few walking breakes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="5" />30 minutes – I will run all the way in a moderate pace</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="6" />20 minutes – I will run all the way in a very high pace</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="392"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my `<form>`:

```
<form name="fitness" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return fitnessValidate(this)">
```

But it submits even if the user has not selected an option. Can someone tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if(document.getElementById("fitness").value==null)

Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid. *getElementById* will return one of them (first? last? depending on browser), not all of them.

Since all of them have a value, the above expression will always return *false*.

Anyhow, in order to be successful (be submitted with the form), form controls must have a name, so just remove all the IDs (they don't do anything useful).

Also, having a control with a name of *submit* replaces the form's submit method, so if you attempt:

```
form.submit();
```

you'll get an error as you're trying to call the element named submit, not the method. So don't give a control a name of "submit".

So the function can be:

```
function fitnessValidate(form) {
  var radios = form.fitness;
  var oneChecked = false;

  for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen && !oneChecked; i++) {
    oneChecked = radios[i].checked;
  }

  if (!oneChecked) {
    // no radio is selected, show error and stop submission
    window.alert("Please select an option");
    return false;
  }
  // No need to return true, any value other than false will allow the form to submit
}
```

That will loop over all the controls with a name of "fitness" and return false if none of them are checked, or *undefined* if one is checked (so the form will submit).

The above will work in any browser that supports javascript.

#### Edit

As [@Quasimodo's clone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741589/quasimodos-clone) suggests, the loop can be simplified to return if a checked radio button is found and do the error thing otherwise:

```
function fitnessValidate(form) {
  var radios = form.fitness;

  for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) return;
  }

  // no radio is selected, show error and stop submission
  window.alert("Please select an option");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: When iteration is used, you could just return if a checked radio button is found. `for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) return;` No if statement and no oneChecked variable is needed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

Remove "ID" from the radio button and Fixed your JS function

```
<form name="fitness" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return fitnessValidate(this)">
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left:15px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="1" />More than 1 hour – I will walk slowly and take several breaks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="2" />1 hour - I will walk all the way in a normal pace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="3" />45 minutes– I will walk all the way in a fast pace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="4" />35 minutes – I will run in at an easy pace and take a few walking breakes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="5" />30 minutes – I will run all the way in a moderate pace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="radio" name="fitness" value="6" />20 minutes – I will run all the way in a very high pace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="392">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fitnessValidate(form) { // Javascript function to check whether the user has     selected some fitness option   

   var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName("fitness");
   var checked = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
       if (radiobuttons[i].checked) {
           checked = true;
           return true; // This function will only return true when user has selected a fitness option
       }
   }

if (!checked) {
       window.alert("Please select an option"); // If user has not selected an option providing an alert
       return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicated the ID of the input element. ID duplicate is not allowed in HTML and W3C. Please check this.

```
<input type="radio" id="fitness" name="fitness" value="6"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should judge by name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function fitnessValidate(form){  // Javascript function to check whether the user has selected some fitness option
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("fitness");
        var flag = false;
        for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
        if(radios[i].checked){  // Checking whether user has selected some option          
           flag=true;
        }
        if(flag){
            return true;
        }else{
           window.alert("Please select an option");  // If user has not selected an option providing an alert
           return false;
        }

   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code:

```
function fitnessValidate(form)
{ return null !== form.querySelector('input[name=fitness]:checked')
      || alert("Please select an option") || false;
}
```

However, there's a much better way to register event listeners:

```
// form tag should have the id="form-fitness" attribute
document.getElementById('form-fitness').addEventListener('submit', function(ev)
{ if(null === this.querySelector('input[name=fitness]:checked'))
  { alert("Please select an option");
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

btw.: As already mentioned in other answers, an ID must be unique. Remove the ID attributes of the radio buttons or give them unique ones. Your code invalid.